# how to transfer all table schema from one database to another database using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I want to compare/transfer table schema of all tables of one database(lets say Database2) to another(lets say Database1) and i want this to happen through a stored procedure, could you please help me in it?

```
database 1 
table employee 
empname column is varchar(3) 

database 2 
table employee 
empname column is varchar(5)
```

Given the above,  after running the script the `empname` column of `database1` table `employee` should also become `varchar(5)`. I have written the below stored procedure for the same but its not working

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompareSchemaScript]
(
@ix_sys_error int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @LogError INT, @PrimaryKey INT,@ErrorMessage nvarchar(2000)
EXEC log_ins @LogError, @PrimaryKey,5,1,NULL,1,'Script Started' 
 ALTER SCHEMA Database1.tables TRANSFER Database2.tables;  
EXEC log_ins @LogError, @PrimaryKey,7,1,NULL,1,'Script Completed Successfully' 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH          
     SELECT @ix_sys_error = ERROR_NUMBER()          
     SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()          
     EXEC ix_sys_event_log_ins @LogError, @PrimaryKey,6,1,NULL,1,@ErrorMessage,NULL          
END CATCH  

IF (@ix_sys_error !=0)          
RETURN 1          
ELSE          
RETURN 0          
END
```

Comment: If you don't know whether it will work, why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @TabAlleman Its not working i have checked.

Comment: See the following:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179(v=sql.110).aspx